# How to remove numbers or character

Tags: sql

select model from Data:

```
1  2005 TF6 F-150   
2  2006 TB7 Expedition 2003
```

I want to see the data like  below

```
2005 TF6 F-150   
2006 TB7 Expedition
```

I tried different approches  but nothing seems to be working

since i have the number at the end of one  and  two  it removes that number as well is there a anyway we could only remove the digits from the end;

Comment: If you don't want the first column, don't include it in your `select`

Comment: Which approaches have you tried?

Comment: i have tried splitting the column from numbers and character but i am getting 150 too.. which I  dont want  and tried using the substr as well but its takes away the values from other rows as well

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you are looking for... But you can search for the first space and get eferything after.

```
select trim(substr(model, instr(model, ' '))) from Data
```